# Table + form not submitting

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

In my further attempt of making a relative database thingy i came across weird (for me, at least) problem of my form not submiting any values. My blessing will flow onto anyone who helps me find problem in this code:

```
***in index.cshtml***
<form method = "get" action="update.cshtml" id="mainForm"></form>
    <table class="database">
       <tr>
           <th>Ocena z informatyki</th>
           <th>Ocena z fizyki</th>
           <th>Ocena z matematyki</th>
           <th>No.</th>
       </tr> 
        @foreach(var row in db.Query(queryString)) 
        {
            <tr>
            <td id="it" ondblclick="edit(this)">@row.it</td>
            <td id="physics" ondblclick="edit(this)">@row.physics</td>
            <td id="math" ondblclick="edit(this)">@row.maths</td>
            <td id="no">@row.no</td>
            <td><button value="Submit changes" onclick="submit" form="mainForm">Submit changes</button></td>
            </tr>                
        }
        </table>
```

And here is "edit()" function:

```
***in scripts.js***
function edit(elm) {
    if (elm.getElementsByTagName('input').length > 0) return;

    var value = elm.innerHTML;
    elm.innerHTML = '';

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('value', value);
    input.setAttribute('form', 'mainForm');
    elm.appendChild(input);
    input.focus();
}
```

Comment: this should help: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios
or watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsfOFL4bXXA ( it has a demo of creating a form + submit)

Comment: form action property should looks like this: action="@Url.Action("Home", "Update")"

Answer (score 0):

If you use "method = get" to submit a form you need to append the data to the querystring.